# Microservice architecturs and layers

Tags: architecture, microservices

Let's discuss the architecture of a microservice environment. We are having a discussion internally at our company and I'd like some feedback. What I'm having serious thoughts about are an orchestration layer (code duplication, more moving parts changing an api).

### Option one - with orchestration layer:

webapp -> orchestration -> service -> persistance

api -> api gw -> orchestration -> service -> persistance

In this case services are not allowed to talk to each other. Aggregated services in orchestration layer

### Option one - without orchestration layer:

webapp -> service -> persistance

api -> api gw -> service -> persistance

Here services are allowed to talk to each other, aggregated services exist here.

#### Specific questions:

- Where does billing belong?
- Which solution do you prefer? Pros/cons.
- Other suggestions?

Comment: This is not the sort of question that SO is suitable for. As a long-time member, you're aware of that. Flagging for closing as "too broad."

Comment: shit.. :-) Where do I ask this type of question then?

Comment: @TheresiaSofiaSnow can you elaborate a bit more on what you put behind "api gw", "orchestration" and "service" ? Is it the *micro*service or some internal service ?

Comment: Me too would like to know where within StackExchange galaxy questions about Software Architecture should go to? @MikeC

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions

Answer (score 2):

> webapp -> orchestration -> **service** -> persistance
>
> api -> api gw -> orchestration -> **service** -> persistance (emphasis mine)

Can we back up a bit? I'd like to question the terminology used here.

To me, the above stacks dont make much sense within the context of SOA.

You have the *service* sandwiched between things called *orchestration* and *persistence*. However, in an SOA design, all of the above elements are necessary to create a single service.

But what *is* persistence in your example? Whatever it is, it would appear to be outside of the service. So how can the service persist data? The web app/API also appear to be outside the service. So how can the service display it's data on the screen?

If you look at the tenets of SOA, specifically the second tenet:

> Services are [autonomous](http://serviceorientation.com/serviceorientation/service_autonomy)

If services are supposed to be autonomous, then the service needs to be responsible for [persisting it's own data](http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html). The service also needs to be take responsiblity for displaying it's internal state via the UI.

> What I'm having serious thoughts about are an orchestration layer

It should follow on from this that services should also take responsibility for how internal state is communicated to the outside world, including between itself and other services.

If the service needs to consume data from another service, it becomes the responsibility of the consumer service to get that data. If the service's state changes, it is the responsibility of that service to allow the outside world to know about the state change.

Orchestration is a [concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concern_(computer_science)), just like persistence, instrumentation, etc, and so in the context of SOA is best implemented in a distributed, autonomous manner, rather than as a centalised one.

So, in answering your questions:

> Where does billing belong?

Billing belongs to it's own vertical service stack, comprising UI views, persistence, orchestration, communications, deployment and management.

> Which solution do you prefer? Pros/cons.

As stated, I don't think the choice should be made at the level the question is posed. I think that whichever services require orchestration should be take responsibility for it.

> Other suggestions?

Have a look at [this](https://vimeo.com/5022174) if you haven't already seen it.